# Possible to place multiple SelectElements in list

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm wondering if its possible to place multiple `selectItems` in a list so I can run through them and randomly select something.

This is what I have so far:

```
IList<SelectElement> allLifeStyleDD = (IList<SelectElement>)driver.FindElements(By.XPath(lifeStyleDD));
Console.WriteLine("Size: " + allLifeStyleDD.Count);

var random = new Random();
var options = new List<string>{"Never", "Daily", "Weekly",
                               "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Annually"};


foreach (SelectElement element in allLifeStyleDD)
{
    int index = random.Next(options.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Size: " + allLifeStyleDD.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("About to set: " + options[index]);

    element.SelectByText(options[index]);
}
```

But I get an error stating the specified cast is not valid.

The idea is to randomly assign all the found dropdowns each time this is executed.

Comment: you mean you have multiple dropdowns and you want to select randomly from anyone of them?

Comment: Welcome to stack @BrianMitchell :) Which line throws the error?

Comment: i have multiple dropdowns and i want to randomly set all of them

Comment: Brian, in your comment in budi's answer you said you found something that works. Why not post it as an answer for anyone else who has the same need?

Comment: Will do Mark, All done

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that throws the exception:

```
IList<SelectElement> allLifeStyleDD =
    (IList<SelectElement>)driver.FindElements(By.XPath(lifeStyleDD));
```

`FindElements` returns an `IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`, which cannot be cast into an `IList<SelectElement>`.

---

Alternatively, you can use LINQ:

```
IList<SelectElement> allLifeStyleDD = 
    driver.FindElements(By.XPath(lifeStyleDD))
        .Select(element => new SelectElement(element))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same error, i took a different approach in the end which works

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I've updated my LINQ solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach to this, I found that putting multiple dropdown objects in a list was difficult but im convinced its possible so i may try again at a later date.

However, I found each dropbox I wanted to interact with had the same id but with a incremented number on the end.

So, in the end, i did this

```
var random = new Random();
var options = new List<string> { "Never", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Annually" };

        for (int i = 1; i < 23; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(options.Count);
            general.waitForElementAndSelectDD("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl" + i.ToString(), options[index]);
        }
```

The waitforElementAndSelectDD is just a way of not typing it out each time

```
public void waitForElementAndSelectDD(String dropdown, String option){
        new WebDriverWait(driver,  

        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(longTimeout))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(dropdown))));

        SelectElement dropDown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(dropdown)));

        dropDown.SelectByText(option);
    }
```

I hope this helps someone